# Do/While infinitely loops issue c#

Tags: c#, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-sharp

I am automating interaction with a website where the user will have to refresh the pages n times manually (sometimes 3 or 5 or even longer) so that the buttons appear on the web page. To overcome this issue, I created a do / while loop that should refresh the page until the button is visible so it can be clicked. The problem is it goes out of sync and infinitely loops. I tried the script below, but it still doesn't stop refreshing. Any idea how to make it stop refreshing as soon as the element is visible? by default, the element will not be visible, so the user will have to refresh the page first. The refresh works, but it is very quick, and it doesn't give enough time to check the state of visibility of the button, and maybe that's why it goes into an infinite loop

```
int retries = 0;
bool isElementVisible = false;
do {
  await Page.ReloadAsync(new PageReloadOptions() { Timeout = 5000 });
  isElementVisible = await Page.IsVisibleAsync("input[name='elementname']");
  retries ++;
while (!isElementVisible)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `IsVisibleAsync` will resolve to false immediately.
You could wait for visible with some timeout using `WaitForSelectorAsync`. For instance, 5 seconds:

```
int retries = 0;
bool isElementVisible = false;
do {
  await Page.ReloadAsync(new PageReloadOptions() { Timeout = 5000 });
  try {
    // The default State is Visible
    await Page.WaitForSelectorAsync("input[name='elementname']", new(){ Timeout = 5000});
    isElementVisible = true;
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    retries ++;
  }
} while (!isElementVisible)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It works on the same page but for the next page, it keeps refreshing the button and not clicking on it. is it possible to click and wait for a few seconds before moving to the next task?  await Page.ClickAsync("input[name='elementname']" with a delay here?